# nested form ids within jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How does one get a nested form id while using jquery?

lets say the form is

```
<form id="search-theme-form">
<div id = "search">
   <div id="edit-search-theme-form-1-wrapper" class="form-item">
   </div>
   <input id="edit-submit" class="form-submit btn">
</div>
</form>
```

will it be

```
$('#search-theme-form').submit(function () {
    $('#search #edit-submit').click(function () {
        if ($("#search input:text").val() == "Search this community..." || $("#search input:text").val() == "") {
            alert("Please enter a search term");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: 1 mistake in your code `$("$edit-submit").click()` should be `$("#edit-submit").click()`

Comment: Can you clarify your question, it doesn't make much sense. Thanks!

Comment: For `#search input:text` to work you’ll have to specify `type="text"` on your `<input>`.

Comment: I still don’t get your question. What does your jQuery code have to do with nested IDs? What’s your problem with the code you provided?

Comment: my question is that if i have a form with nested div, how do i find the form id while applying jquery to it. Any examples would be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery uses CSS-type selectors. To get a sub-id select like

```
jQuery('#search #edit-submit');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a form tag. :)